# When we should use "is directly followed by" or "is indirectly followed by" in creating closed funnel in Google Analytics for firebase

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I am trying to create closed funnel in Google Analytics for Firebase dashboard for a mobile application using Analysis feature which they announced this year. While creating steps for funnel I am getting option "is directly followed by" or "is indirectly followed by" for every next step. When I choose "is directly followed by" option funnel shows no event but screen are in sequence in the mobile application and when I choose "is indirectly followed by"  it shows me events in funnel. Please let me if any body knows clear meaning of "is directly followed by" or "is indirectly followed by" options. I done Google search but I didn't get proper documentation of this.